# how to retrieve particular records from SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I need to get data from DB & displayed it as list with pagination.

i.e. If i retrieved 4 items..i need to display first 2 items in first page.

When i click next button.,remaining 2 items should be displayed which replaces old 2.

How could i restrict data from DB as 2 like that?

My code..

```
 db.open();

   // db.insertTitle("Money");
    //db.insertTitle("make");
    //db.insertTitle("make");
    //db.insertTitle("make");

    Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {          
              String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("user"));
              results.add( firstName );
           } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayAll.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

    db.close();
}
```

My DBAdapter..

public Cursor getAllTitles() 
        {

```
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
                    {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_USER,
                }, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }
```

Comment: @vnshetty yeah..if i have 4 rows totally..i need to display first 2 on first page.Then next 2 rows when button clicks..

Comment: why you are retrieving data at time . you can write code for click event no? i'm not clear about your doubt...

Comment: you have to change in query . you have to set limit in query to fetch number of data . can you give me query which is retrieve data from database ?

Comment: No.i retrieved all data from DB & have to display it by pagination.For ex.If i have 4 rows as "Pepsi","coke","mirinda","sprite"..when i run app.,i should display firstly "pepsi","coke" in a listview.When i click next button i've replce it by "mirinda","sprite".Got it?

Comment: hi sudhir please post your query i will give you new query to fetch data as you want.. definition of this db.getAllTitles(); function . what you write in this function ?

Comment: @Chirag i've posted..see that buddy

Comment: please replace your query with this...

Comment: @Chirag replace with what?i've send u the code to ur mail..pls see it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
public Cursor getAllRecords(int page,int totalRecord)
{
   return db.rawQuery("select * from your_table_name limit "+(page-1)*totalRecord+","+totalRecord, null);
}
```

Where limit = how many record you want at a time if you want 2 record then pass limit = 2 if 10 record then set limit = 10..
and page = first initial page variable with 1 and when second time you fetch next record increase your page variable by 1 .